# LoadLibrary failed with error 998: Invalid access to memory location

Tags: android, adt, android-virtual-device, loadlibrary

I am trying to do the get started android app - there are two locations and two methods I have tried, both same result:

> LoadLibrary failed with error 998:
>   Invalid access to memory location

Step 5 from [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidInstallation/article.html).
Running the app from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html).

I have installed the standalone adt app from [the official SDK site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Please note I initially had the 64-bit jdk installed AND installed the 64-bit adt standalone version. I received the same symptom. So I, subsequently, installed the 32-bit jdk and then installed the 32-bit adt standalone, and got the same issue.

**adt version info**

Android Developer Tools
Build: v21.0.1-543035

**Java version**

java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

**My machine info**

Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1
Studio XPS 7100
AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1035T Processor 2.60 GHz
6.00 GB RAM
64-bit Operating System

Comment: Can you please post your log output (which you can do by typing: adb logcat)

Comment: K:\General\dads\tools\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform
-tools>adb logcat
- waiting for device -

Comment: I did the above command and nothing happened. I tried to start the app and got the same error.

Comment: You have more then 1 device attached.  Make sure you have 1 emulator or device attached, and do same command.  Then search for NULLPointer (likely).

Comment: When I go into the AVD Manager and press start (after following instructions for adding a new one in getting started), then launch, I get the error. So not sure how to attach an emulator if that is not how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to android-sdk/Tools and rename emulator-arm.exe to emulator.exe. You may make backup of current old emulator.exe

Comment: k the emulator seems to show, thought I get the following errors when I launch it from eclipse avd manager
Starting emulator for AVD 'AvdTest'
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: Could not load DLL!
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: Then I tried to launch the test app and nothing happens, expected hello world to pop onto the emulator, but nothing appeared

[2013-03-18 20:31:59 - MyTestApp] ------------------------------
[2013-03-18 20:31:59 - MyTestApp] Android Launch!
[2013-03-18 20:31:59 - MyTestApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-18 20:31:59 - MyTestApp] Performing com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity activity launch

Comment: [2013-03-18 20:31:59 - MyTestApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-03-18 20:32:04 - MyTestApp] Uploading MyTestApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-03-18 20:32:05 - MyTestApp] Installing MyTestApp.apk...
[2013-03-18 20:32:13 - MyTestApp] Success!
[2013-03-18 20:32:13 - MyTestApp] Starting activity com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

Comment: k, never mind just had to wait longer for the emulator to come up, then run the test app.